# Run a function when an api route is mounted

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am using express router for my app. I need to run a function when a particular route is mounted. I have two files, `index.route.js` and `currentUser.route.js`

`index.route.js`

```
import currentUserRoutes from './currentUser.route';
const router = express.Router(); 
//mounts the '/me' route on currentUserRoutes
router.use('/me', currentUserRoutes);
export default router;
```

`currentUser.route.js`

```
const router = express.Router();
//line below throws an error
router.on('mount' , () => {console.log("me route mounted")});

router.route('/')
    .get(currentUserCtrl.get)

export default router;
```

It throws an error saying router.on is not a function, I have tried placing the `router.on`  part in `index.route.js` too, but there too I am getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to run the function I needed using `router.all('/*', currentUserCtrl.load);` .

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
router.on('mount' , function(){console.log("me route mounted")});
```

Comment: I did try that, Same issue

Comment: const router = require(express).Router(); do this

Comment: I am importing express at the top of my file